# Is there a tool for conversion of IPA into X-Sampa?

Tags: phonetics, ipa, resource-request, transcription, sampa

I need to transcribe text into X-Sampa, but I am an IPA transcriber, so for simplicity purposes I will transcribe in IPA and will then try to convert into X-Sampa. Is there any tool that would automate this process for me?

It doesn't have to be free, I can pay. ;)

Comment: If there's none, I'll make one. :)

Comment: I finished the job now by just replacing the characters using a macro in Notepad++, but we will most likely do this more often in future, so a tool would still be warmly  welcome! ;)

Answer (score 3):

http://tools.lgm.cl/xsampa.html

This tool allows for two-way conversion between IPA and X-SAMPA.